# How to start tracking previously ignored file?

Tags: git

My `.gitignore` contains `dist` folder.

I have a file: `dist/monorepo-docker-build-helper.js` which I need to track from now on (it's auto generated from a build-process).

`.gitignore` file now:

```
dist
!dist/monorepo-docker-build-helper.js
```

When running `git status`, `dist/monorepo-docker-build-helper.js` is never listed, even after it was changed.

*I looked at other answers*: `git add dist/monorepo-docker-build-helper.js -f` helps but when there is a new change, `git status` **doesn't show it**.

What can I do to permanently add `dist/monorepo-docker-build-helper.js` to git?

Comment: Did `git add dist/monorepo-docker-build-helper.js` (without the `-f`-option) also work or did you need it? In case you need it, it seems the file is still getting ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you need to ignore not the `dist` folder itself, but everything in it (`dist/*`). This way the exclude afterwards will work [as stated in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5534865/12507396).

You should really rethink why you want to commit generated files in the first place, because it's a bad practice to do so.

Comment: it's working. But I have multiple `dist` folders inside the project. after trying your solution, git tries to follow all `dist` folders.

Comment: by adding third line to `.gitignore`: `packages/**/dist` it seems that now only one file from one `dist` folder is tracked by git.

Comment: Huh, strange enough. Seems that the [pattern format](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format) interprets the lines relative as soon as any slash is in there.
The both lines `/dist/*` combined with `/!dist/myfile.js` (or `!/dist/myfile.js`?) (note the **prefixed slash** should at least be sufficient, can you confirm that?

Answer (score 1):

I believe in this case you have to exclude `dist/*` in the first rule, otherwise for Git the dist folder does not exist.